# How can I target a specific group of siblings in a flat hierarchy?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Assume you have this HTML:

```
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Note that the hierarchy is flat.

Now try to select the "middle pair" of `<p>` elements. Is this possible? I really can't figure out how.

This selector only grabs the first `<p>` following the `<h1>`:

```css
h1:nth-of-type(2) + p
```

But this selector grabs the correct pair of `<p>` elements *plus* all the following `<p>` elements that appear after the pair we want:

```css
h1:nth-of-type(2) ~ p
```

Is it possible?

*No JavaScript. No markup changing. Generic solution. Any number of `<h1>`s or `<p>`s are allowed, and the number two, in this case, is arbitrary.*

I'm thinking maybe this is possible using some using the `:not()` selector, but I can't seem to figure it out. Kind of like selecting the "general siblings" and then excluding as necessary, or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the way the general sibling combinator works, it is not possible to limit a selection of siblings to a specific range or group, even of consecutive siblings. Even the `:not()` selector won't be of any help here.

You *will* have to use JavaScript to target the right elements. jQuery's [`.nextUntil()` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil) immediately springs to mind.