# CSS general sibling selector multiple times in a single document

Tags: css, css-selectors, tinymce

Looking for a way to achieve a certain visual effect without altering HTML markup I stumbled upon a CSS `x ~ y` general sibling selector, but unfortunately it behaves differently than I would hope for (according to its description in spec and testing as well).

We are trying to color all elements following a certain element, and then stop coloring after another element appears. However, there may be many sequences of start/stop coloring in the document, and the `~` selector cascade like all others, the *clear color* styling overrules the *start color* styling after a point in the document to its end.

It's a concept similar to syntax highlighting, but since its inside a *TinyMCE* window for which I want to obtain a clean HTML with no additional classes or inline styling, dynamically coloring elements with inline styling or classes like syntax highlighting plugins do.

The HTML we have is:

```
<h1 class="redbelow">Bold below</h1>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<h1 class="normalbelow">Normal below</h1>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<h1 class="redbelow">Bold below</h1>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.redbelow ~ p {
    color: red;
}
.normalbelow ~ p {
    color: black;
}
```

*(codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPYoyz)*

Now only the first two paragraphs are red, but I'm looking for a way to have the first two **and** the last two red, with the ones in the middle black.

Is there by any chance some hack and/or another approach I could try to achieve that without heavy DOM manipulation with JavaScript on keyboard events?

Comment: No...you really need javascript. Any other CSS would be **highly** dependent on your **specific** HTML and is unlikely to be dynamic,

Comment: A hackish `.normalbelow ~ p ~ .redbelow ~ p`  crossed my mind - it seems to work as expected, but to support indefinite document length, the deeply chained `~` operatorors would have to be either pre-generated programatically to cater for dozens of occurences, or dynamically injected.

Comment: Exactly...that's why JS is ideal here. or just wrap the the headings and associated paragraphs into separate divs / articles which would be the obvious option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I target a specific group of siblings in a flat hierarchy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330757/how-can-i-target-a-specific-group-of-siblings-in-a-flat-hierarchy)

Comment: Yeah, obvious, but unapplicable - we have a fully editable and available to users TinyMCE instance in which we allow inserting simple templating syntax elements - it's for visually denoting what kind of stuff is between those syntax elements. I have no control on what's there and TinyMCE allows to edit out almost everything we would dynamically insert there.

`nextUntil()` from jQuery as BoltClock suggests seems to be the best fit there.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it up using divisions:

```
<div class="redbelow">
  <h1>Bold below</h1>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>

<div class="normalbelow">
  <h1>Normal below</h1>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

And in your css file:

```
.redbelow p {
    color: red;
}
.normalbelow p {
    color: black;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, I didn't mention in the question clearly that I have no control on the markup to do what you'd normally do when creating a document yourself :) The use case makes JavaScript perhaps the best fit.