# Anything similar to "until" in CSS selector?

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml

I would like to get movie names available between "tracked_by" id to "buzz_off" id. I have already created a selector which can grab names after "tracked_by" id. However, my intention is to let the script do the parsing UNTIL it finds "buzz_off" id. The elements within which the names are:

```
html = '''
<div class="list">
  <a id="allow" name="allow"></a>
 <h4 class="cluster">Allow</h4>
 <div class="base min"><a href="...">Sally</a></div> 
 <div class="base max"><a href="..">Blood Diamond</a></div>
  <a id="tracked_by" name="tracked_by"></a>
 <h4 class="cluster">Tracked by</h4>
 <div class="base min"><a href="..">Gladiator</a></div>
 <div class="base max"><a href="..">Troy</a></div>
   <a id="buzz_off" name="buzz_off"></a>
 <h4 class="cluster">Buzz-off</h4>
 <div class="base min"><a href="..">Heat</a></div>
 <div class="base max"><a href="..">Matrix</a></div>
</div>
'''

from lxml import html as htm
root = htm.fromstring(html)
for item in root.cssselect("a#tracked_by ~ div.base a"):
    print(item.text)
```

The selector I've tried with (also mentioned in the above script):

```
a#tracked_by ~ div.base a
```

Results I'm having:

```
Gladiator
Troy
Heat
Matrix
```

Results I would like to get:

```
Gladiator
Troy
```

Btw, I would like to parse the names using this selector not to style.

Comment: [No can do with a selector.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330757/how-can-i-target-a-specific-group-of-siblings-in-a-flat-hierarchy/13330785#13330785) You'll need additional code for this.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is a reference for css selectors. As you can see, it doesn't have any form of logic, as it is not a programming language. You'd have to use a `while not` loop in python and handle each element one at a time, or append them to a list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Treehee. If that is the case then I don't thing it is necessary to borrow any logic from python to deal with it; rather, I would easily go for xpath using this expression "//div[./preceding-sibling::h4[1]='Tracked by']//text()" which is able to serve the purpose just fine. As I prefer css selector in most of the cases while scraping data from web, I would like to learn it's limitation as well. Thanks.